# Testing Pusher with Capybara Poltergeist

Tags: capybara, pusher, poltergeist

I've been trying to test a pusher app with Poltergeist. So far I've only had success with `capybara-webkit`. I've created a [minimal example app](https://github.com/akshayrawat/pusher-webkit-vs-poltergeist/blob/master/README.md) which demonstrates this in a [spec](https://github.com/akshayrawat/pusher-webkit-vs-poltergeist/blob/master/spec/send_messages_spec.rb). The spec passes with `capybara-webkit` but fails with `Poltergeist`.

Am I missing something or is this type of Pusher (WebSocket) testing not possible with Poltergeist at the moment ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried just making a native `WebSocket` connection to see if WebSockets are supported? If not, the pusher-js client will try to download external JS files (assuming you're using the one from the CDN). That could cause additional problems. It may also be worth trying to capture the debug output from pusher-js. See: http://pusher.com/docs/debugging#pusher_logging

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your Pusher javascript library to 2.1.5 (or higher) and it should work (assuming you are also using PhantomJS 1.9 or higher).

Poltergeist automates PhantomJS. PhantomJS does support WebSockets, however it's an older version (until PhantomJS 2.0 comes out, see https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/11018). The Pusher javascript library also supports various versions of WebSockets so in theory they *should* work together.

In practice I had trouble getting it to work when using version 2.1.3 of the Pusher JS library (and from the date of this question I imagine you were using an even older version). As of 2.1.5 my poltergeist tests are successfully testing Pusher functionality.